# How to set title after html

Tags: php, html

For example you have output `<head>` tag and don't know `title` at that moment.

You will know title at the end of code.

How to set title from that place?

Simplified template looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>We don't know title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <article>
            <!--at this place we include code, that output article and know title-->
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I want to set title in script, that included after all code.

Comment: @M-A-X, Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service, but a place to get help with code you are writing.  If you post your attempt to solve this problem, you are more likely to get useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to try, the code that is calculating the title I assume occurs after you have outputted the `<head>` HTML. Are you able to move this code to *before* the `<head>` and store any HTML in a variable to be `print`ed after?

Otherwise you would need to set the answer using a script that executes when the page is fully loaded. Something like

```
//index.php
<head>
 <title></title> //blank title
</head>
<body>
 <?php
  //code that finds title
   $title = 'I am set later';
  ?>

//All other page output

 <script>
  //This will run at the end of the body after everything else.
  document.title = <?php echo $title; ?>

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

edit: nicely caught

Comment: Thanks. How to do this without js?
More seo friendy.

Comment: Use a combination of my option 1 and Admed's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908236/5746996 ; can explain more if you need

Comment: @Tobin did you run this code? The <?php ?> tag doesn't works for me inside <script> tag